Fingerprint scanner for Honor MagicBook x 15
The system does not see the fingerprint scanner on the Honor MagicBook x 15 laptop. What to do and how to solve it?
I tried to enter commands into the terminal, which I will not say for sure. I tried sudo pam-auth-update, I noted the fingerprint scanner there, but to no avail.
